# Disable DoubleClicks

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to disable double clicks on buttons and currently the only way I know is to handle the `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` and set the `e.Handled = true`.

Is there a way to do this in a button style?   Or even better, disable double clicks application wide?

Comment: Why is that ? If you don't put any code in the event, nothing happen when this is happening right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an attached behavior ([see this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx)).  For example, say I create an attached behavior called DisableDoubleClickAttachedBehavior which handles the double click mouse event and sets e.Handled = true.

Then, you can nicely set the property via a style in XAML:

```
    <Style x:Key="DisableDoubleClickStyle">
        <Setter Property="p:DisableDoubleClickAttachedBehavior.Enabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource DoubleClickDisabledStyle}">Hi!</Button>
```

Or, you can override the style for all buttons (like you wanted):

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="p:DisableDoubleClickAttachedBehavior.Enabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>
```

I tested this and it seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done in a style or application-wide. Best bet might be a class derived from `Button` that includes that event handler by default.

Comment: This is a good approach. Inheritance is your friend. Create a sub class of button which handles the double click the way you want, then instead of using just the button class, use your sub class.