# How to disable double click behaviour in a WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

In my `TreeView`, I have different events for `MouseDown`/`MouseUp`, etc but when I do it fast enough the `TreeView` expands/collapses the `TreeNode`. I don't want this baked-in behaviour.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037042/disable-doubleclicks/6037293#6037293

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could suppress the double click event of TreeViewItem like so:

xaml:

```xml
<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseDoubleClick="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 1" IsExpanded="True" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 2.1" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="MyItem" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 2.2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="MyItem" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

code:

```
private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //this will suppress the event that is causing the nodes to expand/contract 
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to msdn [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.previewmousedoubleclick.aspx):

> Although this routed event seems to
>   follow a tunneling route through an
>   element tree, it actually is a direct
>   routed event that is raised along the
>   element tree by each UIElement... 
>   Control authors who want to handle
>   mouse double clicks should use the
>   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event when
>   ClickCount is equal to two. This will
>   cause the state of Handled to
>   propagate appropriately in the case
>   where another element in the element
>   tree handles the event.

I'm not sure if this why you are having issues or not, but we'll do it the MSDN way and use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead:

xaml:

```
<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 1" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 2.1" >
            <TreeViewItem Header="MyItem" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 2.2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="MyItem" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

code:

```
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount > 1)
    {
        //here you would probably want to include code that is called by your
        //mouse down event handler.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I've tested this and it works no matter how many times i click

Comment: Just tried but it still does it. I wrote `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` instead of `TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseDoubleClick`, does it matter?

Comment: The example I gave works either way. Perhaps you could post your code, maybe something is interfering?

Comment: Thanks, let me try it in a new project then just to be sure.

Comment: Just tried it in a new project, when I try it for several clicks, it still expands/collapse. Like double click is suppressed most of the time, but more than 2 clicks like 3 clicks still seem to expand/collapse it. Can you try it out like that? I don't know why MS would add a behaviour like this.

Comment: I found how the double click still expands/collapses. First select the node, and the double click on it, otherwise the first click goes to selecting it. But to select it, double click on the node, and another double click to expand/collapse.

Comment: Hang on, reading about some funny behavior with this on msdn... i have an idea

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it. Can't believe MS is introducing bizarre issues like this.

Comment: Hey man, it works, thanks. Really good effort, can't believe it's this convoluted to disable this nasty "feature".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the expanding/collapsing of the TreeView on DoubleClick, but at the same time use a command for this event, you could use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60869105/1206431